# Libgdx BitmapFont NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I created my project with Freetype, tools, and box2d for intellej, and upon trying to run in android studio:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
```

it gives me a null pointer exception. I have tried manually putting a font in the assests folder but that did not help. I am able to successfully run the default project (the red background and the picture) but have never successfully ran that line.

Comment: Well, calling the default constructor BitmapFont() actually loads a font (Arial-15) in the LibGDX JAR (https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#BitmapFont--). So, perhaps your wrapper class is null or something, or maybe you have some weird thing going on with your LibGDX JAR (unlikely)?

Comment: So what could it be?

Comment: show more code of your class, I think you've some other problem

Comment: show complete error/exception log ?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this line causes the error. Please post the entire stacktrace and the full method where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason may be you're initialising local `BitmapFont` instead of global that you're using in render method.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

    Texture texture;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    BitmapFont font;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        BitmapFont font=new BitmapFont();  // You initialise local, global is still Null

        texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(texture,100,100);
        font.draw(spriteBatch,"HELLO WORLD",100,100); // Now here NPE
        spriteBatch.end();
    }
}
```

Default constructor

```
BitmapFont font=new BitmapFont();
```

Internally create two `FileHandle` one for 
font file `com/badlogic/gdx/utils/arial-15.fnt` and another one for imageFile `com/badlogic/gdx/utils/arial-15.png`. I don't think, it throw NPE may be some other `Exception`.